# How to create a Column in Google Sheets that outputs the values that at some point were the biggest or smallest from another column?

Tags: google-sheets

In this spreadsheet, I have three base columns, "Guess", "Answer" and "Absolute difference". A guess is said to be the best one so far if its absolute difference from the answer is the smallest one among every other that came before it. The same applies to the worst guesses, except that their absolute difference is the biggest one among the ones that came before it.

[image: The base columns]

With this in mind, I was wondering how to create a fourth and fifth column that would output all the previous best and worst guesses. For instance, this is what both of these columns should output based off of the Guesses, Answers and Absolute differences from the 1st picture:

[image: What should be outputted]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=map(A2:A, C2:C, lambda(guess, diff, 
  if( 
    isnumber(diff), 
    hstack( 
      single(filter(A2:guess, C2:diff = min(C2:diff))), 
      single(filter(A2:guess, C2:diff = max(C2:diff))) 
    ), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
))
```

See
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[hstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190756)
and
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: I tried using this formula but it generates multiple lines with the same best guess, I was looking for a way to output the best guesses only once (without leaving blank lines in between too). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The question specifies _"**all** the previous best and worst guesses"_. To show each guess just once, use `unique()`. Please do not present new requirements in comments but [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/173382/edit) the question.

Comment: When you edit the question, also insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Comment: Hey, I managed to work the formula out the way I wanted it to be, but would not have been able to do it without the base formula you provided, so thank you a lot! I'm new to this website so I was pretty unfamiliar with the dynamics and I apologize for that. Either way, thanks for helping me solve my problem :)

Comment: Also here is how it turned out. I'm pretty sure it is not as optimized as it could be, so any feedbacks would be appreciated.

Comment: `=MAP(MAP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(MAP(C2:C; LAMBDA(diff; 
  IF( 
    ISNUMBER(diff);
      FILTER(C2:diff; C2:diff = min(C2:diff)); 
    IFERROR(ø) 
  ) 
)));COUNT(UNIQUE(MAP(C2:C; LAMBDA(diff; 
  IF( 
    ISNUMBER(diff);
      FILTER(C2:diff; C2:diff = min(C2:diff)); 
    IFERROR(ø) 
  ) 
))))-1;1);LAMBDA(id;MATCH(id;C:C;0)));LAMBDA(row;CONCATENATE(INDEX(A:A;row);" on day "; row-1)))`